# How to make the select element the width of its current option

Tags: jquery, css, forms

I'm creating a form and need the select element to expand/contract to the width of its current option. Its current width is its longest option.

CSS can only be used to give the select a fixed width and using the jQuery .width() function on an option returns 0px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select element is completely rendered by the browser. You cannot hook it as far as I know. The only solution is to measure the option by yourself and resize the select element dynamically.

It's not a good solution since it's hard to measure fonts that are not monospaced, but it might be enough.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qqcc5/

```
jQuery('#yourSelect').change(function() {
    optionValue = jQuery('#yourSelect option:selected').val();
    jQuery('#yourSelect').width(20 + (optionValue.length * 8));
});
```

Comment: Nice fix, thanks! First time seeing the change function too. I'll definitely be playing around with this

Answer (score 0):

Like MVP said, you can't, not really. But you can fake it. Here's my approach:

```
function update_select_width() {
    //approximate pixel width of <select>'s arrow button -
    //might not be needed in all browsers, not sure
    var buffer = 24;

    //create a hidden <span> containing the selected option's text
    var temp_span = $('<span>').html($(this).val()).hide();

    //add the <span> to the DOM to give it measurable width
    $('body').append(temp_span);

    //set the width of the select box to the width of the <span>,
    //plus the buffer for the arrow button
    $(this).width($(temp_span).width() + buffer);

    //remove the <span> we created
    $(temp_span).remove();
}

//call once to set initial width
update_select_width.call($('#select_id'));

$('#select_id').change(update_select_width);
```

This should be accurate to the real width of the `<option>`—as long as the font for `<option>` and `<span>` are the same—as it creates and measures a physical element in the DOM containing the text you want.

- Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rfwWR/11/

I used `M` (the widest character in the English alphabet) and `i` (the narrowest) to demonstrate that character width does not matter in this solution.

Comment: I'll need to apply the same css rules somehow. I was thinking this as an improvement to MVP's method

Comment: @user2658368 what css rules? (also, i've updated with a fiddle)

Comment: The font size and font family of the select element. Also change needs to be run once the page loads, in case the first option isn't the longest

Comment: @user2658368 see my updated answer for how to set the initial width. in regards to css - most browsers don't let you style `<select>` very much, and certainly not `<option>`. there are workarounds though; try google for more